# Move navbar item to the right

Tags: markdown

[image: Live page preview image]
Hello all, I am very new to Markdown and want to know if it's possible to move my "About&Contact" navbar item in the bluebox (in the image) to the redbox (in the image). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Hugo version 0.122.0 , with the [slick](https://github.com/spookey/slick) theme.

Code:

```
---
title: About Hugo
slug: about
description: About IRG
date: 2024-02-07T10:25:30-05:00
type: page
draft: false
showmetalinks: false
menu:
  main:
    name: About&Contact
    weight: 999
categories: null
tags: null
series: null
---

Hugo is a static site engine written in Go.
```

I have looked through the [theme](https://github.com/spookey/slick) documentation but unfortunately found no solution.

Comment: sounds like you need to put some CSS somewhere...